# Having multiple instances of the same element in a partial order?

Tags: lattice-orders

I was wondering about how to represent a partial order which includes multiple instance of the same element. For example a partial order could include these two nodes: "(a ⋁ b) ⋀ a" and "(a ⋀ b) ⋁ b", and also include different combinations and sub-parts of these.

Linguistically you might take the following sentence:

"John went to see his friend, who owed him 10 dollars.", or:

"a" went to see "b", who owed "a" 10 dollars.

Represented as: (a ⋁ b) ⋀ a

The fundamental idea is that John is mentioned twice, and his friend only once. I wish to represent this fundamental idea as a partial ordered set (or perhaps pre-order), in order to be able to compare it against other such possibilities which might include "John" and "the friend".

⋁ and ⋀ might be meet and join, or alternatively they might be unison and intersection.

Comment: If this were a lattice, then $(a\vee b)\wedge a=a$ and $(a\wedge b)\vee b=b$. I don't know how to represent these sentences with order relations, but if they can be represented as lattices, then it must be in more sophisticated way than the one you presented.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I didn't mean to represent these sentences fully with order relations; only to represent the number of times people are referred to. Although I lack the math competence, I've considered two other ways of representing them with order theory:   1. Truth tables, e. g. John is notated "11" because he is mentioned twice, and the friend is notated "10" because he's only mentioned once. Or we might note in the order relations only the boolean outputs? But I'm not sure how to represent truth tables as order relations.  2. Matrices (they have an y and x) with order relations?